# How to load modules dynamically on package import?

Tags: python, dynamic, import, packaging

Given the following example layout:

```
test/
  test.py
  formats/
    __init__.py
    format_a.py
    format_b.py
```

What I try to archive is, that whenever I `import formats`, the `__init__.py` looks for all available modules in the `formats` subdir, loads them and makes them available (right now simply through a variable, `supported_formats`). If theres a better, more pythonic or otherwise approach to dynamically loading stuff on runtime, based on physical available files, please tell.

#### My Approach

I tried something like this (in `__init__.py`):

```
supported_formats =  [__import__(f[:f.index('.py')]) for f in glob.glob('*.py')]
```

So far I just get it to work, when I run `__init__.py` from the command line (from the formats subdir or from other directories) . But when I import it from `test.py`, it bails on me like this:

`ImportError: No module named format_a.py`

Same when I import it  from the python interpreter, when I started the interpreter in an other directory but the `formats` subdir.

Here's the whole code. It also looks for a specific class and stores one instance of each class in an dict, but loading the modules dynamically is the main part I don't get:

```
def dload(get_cls=True, get_mod=True, key=None, fstring_mod='*.py', fstring_class=''):
  if p.dirname(__file__):
    path = p.split(p.abspath(__file__))[0]
    fstring_mod = p.join(path, fstring_mod)
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Path-Glob:', fstring_mod
  modules = [p.split(fn)[1][:fn.index('.py')] for fn in glob.glob(fstring_mod)]
  print >> sys.stderr, 'Modules:', ', '.join(modules)
  modules = [__import__(m) for m in modules]
  if get_cls:
    classes = {} if key else []
    for m in modules:
      print >> sys.stderr, "-", m
      for c in [m.__dict__[c]() for c in m.__dict__ if c.startswith(fstring_class)]:
        print >> sys.stderr, " ", c
        if key:
          classes[getattr(c, key)] = c
        else:
          classes.append(c)
    if get_mod:
      return (modules, classes)
    else:
      return classes
  elif get_mod:
    return modules

_supported_formats = dload(get_mod=False, key='fid', fstring_mod='format_*.py', fstring_class='Format')
```

#### My Idea

The whole messing with filesystem-paths and the like is probably messy anyway. I would like to handle this with module namespaces or something similar, but I'm kinda lost right now on how start and how to address the modules, so they reachable from anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two fixes you need to make to your code:

1. You should call `__import__(m, globals(), locals())` instead of `__import__(m)`. This is needed for Python to locate the modules within the package.
2. Your code doesn't remove the .py extension properly since you call index() on the wrong string. If it will always be a .py extension, you can simply use `p.split(fn)[1][:-3]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

First you must make it so that your code works regardless of the current working directory. For that you use the `__file__` variable. You should also use absolute imports.

So something like (untested):

```
supported_formats = {}
for fn in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
    if fn.endswith('.py'):
        exec ("from formats import %s" % fn[:-3]) in supported_formats
```

Comment: I did something like that: I attached the `dirname` before the filemask I use for `glob()`. The files where found but I could not import them, I think because I didn't use `globals()` and `locals` in the call to `__import__`.

Comment: Subpackages are imported like "import formats.format_a" so perhaps you have to prepend the import statements with "formats." ?

Answer (score 0):

A module is searched in sys.path. You should be able to extend sys.path with the path to your module. I'm also not really sure whether you can load a module on sys.path with a 'module.py' convention, I would think without '.py' is preferred.

This is obviously not a solution, but may be handy nonetheless.

Comment: The `formats` subdir actually was already on `sys.path`, when I do `import formats` from `test.py`, I couldn't import the files under it from `__init__.py` though. Probably because I don't include `globals()` in the call to `__import__`.

Answer (score 0):

I thought if you did something that, 'formats' would be your package, so when you tell it `import formats` you should be able to access the rest of the modules inside that package, so, you would have something like `formats.format_a.your_method`

Not sure though, I'm just a n00b.

Comment: You're right. But I want Python to do the fetching for me on runtime, because I don't know beforehand the name and number of the files in the `formats/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I came up with after the corrections from interjay. Still not sure if this is good style.

```
def load_modules(filemask='*.py', ignore_list=('__init__.py', )):
  modules = {}
  dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
  if dirname:
    filemask = os.path.join(dirname, filemask)
  for fn in glob.glob(filemask):
    fn = os.path.split(fn)[1]
    if fn in ignore_list:
      continue
    fn = os.path.splitext(fn)[0]
    modules[fn] = __import__(fn, globals(), locals())
  return modules
```